# Find and replace string values with a number

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a matrix of string values...

```
[1,1] = Iris-setosa
[2,1] = Iris-setosa
[3,1] = Iris-setosa
[4,1] = Iris-setosa
[5,1] = Iris-setosa
[6,1] = Iris-setosa
[7,1] = Iris-setosa
[8,1] = Iris-setosa
[9,1] = Iris-setosa
[10,1] = Iris-setosa
[11,1] = Iris-setosa
...
[41,1] = Iris-versicolor
[42,1] = Iris-versicolor
[43,1] = Iris-versicolor
[44,1] = Iris-versicolor
```

I need to convert these strings into a specific number. For example, I need `Iris-versicolor` to be 0.

I tried the following...

```
str_data(str_data == 'Iris-versicolor') = 0
```

But I get errors...

```
error: binary operator '==' not implemented for 'cell' by 'matrix' operations
```

It seems whenever I use the `==` operator I get errors for strings. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strcmp` to compare strings. The equality operator works only if the two arguments are of the same length, or one is scalar.